# Mongoose: Remove referencing ObjectIds using deleteMany hook

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My schema is like the following:

```
const Author = new Schema({
    name: String,
    posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
});

const Post = new Schema({
    text: String,
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Author" }
});
```

If I use `deleteMany()` to delete a bunch of posts, what is the best way to remove the ObjectId entries from the Author's object?

I tried to use the `deleteMany` pre hook, however it only passes how many doc are deleted and not the actual ObjectIds of the posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the query object that is used for the `deleteMany`, and instead use it to query for the documents via `find`. That will give you all of the targeted documents, which you can then delete via `deleteMany`.

Afterwards, if the deleted count matches the length of fetched documents, then you can safely remove all from the author. If the total deleted does not match the length of fetched documents, then you can iterate through all initially-fetched documents, attempt to fetch it, and if it's not found, then that means it's deleted and you can safely remove from author.

Example in typescript:

```js
  const queryObj = { foo: 'bar' };
  const postsCollection = mongoDb.getCollection<{ _id: ObjectId }>('posts');
  const postsToDelete = await postsCollection.find(queryObj).toArray();
  const deleteManyResult = await postsCollection.deleteMany(queryObj);

  if (deleteManyResult.deletedCount === postsToDelete.length) {
    for (const deletedPost of postsToDelete) {
      // delete from author
    }
  } else {
    for (const potentiallyDeletedPost of postsToDelete) {
      const post = await postsCollection.findOne({ _id: potentiallyDeletedPost._id });
      if (!post) {
        // delete from author
      } else {
        // handle non-deleted post
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: My initial thought was pretty similar to your solution here. I was wondering if there is any easier way using hooks because it seems like a pretty common issue. Anyway, thank you for your answer!